# How to import tz data (IANA) into Postgres server

Tags: postgresql, timezone, iana

We're trying to get the timezone data updated on a Windows Postgres install without having to update the server installation.

Background: Our application is using Postgres' built in timezone information and relies on accurate data. Therefore updating Postgres is is not the solution as timezone data is changing too often. 
Is there a way to import / update IANA's timezone data into Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. For anyone having similar needs:

Get yourself cygwin, and run: make TOPDIR=$HOME/tzdir install in order to get the compiled time zone data. Copy that into the share\timezone directory of your postgres install. Restart postgres and off you go!